# Setting a Background Image for Table Cell

Tags: html-table, background-image

This seems like a simple enough task... but I can't seem to find how to do this.  Is it possible to set the background image of a specific cell, then have text on top of it?

I know you can do it for the table as a whole, but what about just a specific cell?

Comment: Can you please provide at a minimum what technologies you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple just add background property like this

```
  <html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>tesssst</td><td background="images.jpg">dfsdf</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```